# Android app - tracking user location and plotting to google map?

Tags: android, google-maps, mobile

How difficult would it be to get a user's location and map it live onto a google map along with the time to complete the route? 
As well as this, when the user completes the route, he or she can save it and upload it to a server, others can then download that route and time themselves against it?

It's a bit more involving that that, but would be interested to know how difficult something like this would be to achieve?

I have limited PHP and C# experience so am not a complete novice to coding but have never developed for a mobile platform before..

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be Mission Impossible. This [link](http://csie-tw.blogspot.com/2009/06/android-driving-direction-route-path.html) provides everything you need. It uses a Google Maps service that is providing the routes data in [KML] format.

Hope this will help you. Good luck!